# Is it possible to change the cursor's color in the micro editor?

Tags: micro-editor

As the title reads, is it possible? I bumped into the problem when trying the bubblegum theme (a light theme) and found the white cursor on a white background a little difficult to read. What I'd like to do is having the cursor be a darker color; preferably through colorschemes.

I am ssh:ed into a raspberyypi that runs micro, from a windows command prompt.

What has been tried is:

- a bit of googling, not finding much.
- changing the colour of a few different "highlight groups" but maybe I've missed something
- running micro on the windows machine. same result, white cursor.

My question therefore is, is it possible? Is it a feature of micro? If so it could be a problem with the command prompt or the ssh, or something else. But if not, then I don't need to search further and just stick with a dark theme.

**UPDATE:**
I fixed by changing the appearance in the windows command prompt. Maybe it just doesn't give up control over the cursor's color? Do any terminal give that control to a program? I still don't know if micro tries to change it tho.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to your question is the [`fakecursor` option](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/blob/master/runtime/help/options.md), but it doesn't offer configuration of color. So, the Answer is no right now.

*You may however suggest this option to be included, like [here](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/issues/2908#issuecomment-1727983269)*